# T-SQL Subquery select with earlier column as paramerter

Tags: sql, sql-server, openquery

I have a question about subqueries and I am uncertain how to google it effectively;
This feels hacky, but it works:

It uses a temporary table (#OrderProcessDates) which I preload with all Ordernr and Processdata data from a LinkedServer MySQL database

```
SELECT Ordernr
, CASE WHEN OrderStartDate IS NULL THEN (SELECT MIN(x.ProcessDate) from (SELECT * FROM #OrderProcessDates WHERE #OrderProcessDates.Ordernummer = Ordernr) as x)
    ELSE OrderStartDate
    END as OrderStartDate
, CASE WHEN OrderStopDate IS NULL AND OrderFinished = 1 THEN (SELECT MAX(x.ProcessDate) from (SELECT * FROM #OrderProcessDates WHERE #OrderProcessDates.Ordernummer = Ordernr) as x)
    ELSE OrderStopDate
    END as OrderStopDate
FROM (
    SELECT Ordernummer as Ordernr
        , OrderStartDate
        , OrderStopDate 
        , OrderFinished
    FROM OPENQUERY([LinkedServer], 
        'SELECT Ordernummer,Table2.DateCreated as OrderStartDate, Table2.DateFinished as OrderStopDate, Table2.Afgemeld as OrderFinished
        FROM Database.Table1
        JOIN Database.Table2 as ordernummers ON Table2.idordernummers = Table1.ordernummer '
    ) as sourcedata 
) as fixedata
```

Is there a better way to use "ordernr" in a subquery; or are you always forced to use a query around the query for the values that are unknown?

Edit: removed earlier question; that contained non-working SQL; this works but need to know if this is "the way"

Comment: *where the Ordernumber is equal to the NULL* Equal sign cannot be used for testing by NULL. In MySQL - use null-safe compare operator `<=>` instead. And remember that you must replace NULL value with unquoted NULL literal during concatenation: `'SELECT MIN(ProcessDate) FROM orderregistratie WHERE Ordernummer <=> ' + COALESCE(Q, 'NULL')`.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: Hi Both, the NULL Check is not the issue; it could've been anything that checks; what I need is the value Q to pass into the OPENQUERY text

Comment: Firstly detect does this is SQL Server problem (OPENQUERY cannot take concatenation expression as a parameter) or MySQL problem (the query text is successfully created and transferred to MySQL, it accepts it but cannot execute).

Comment: *what I need is the value Q to pass into the OPENQUERY text* Only concatenate into SQL text literally then transfer. [OPENQUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is not possible to use queries with parameters.

Comment: See edit in post